# Difference between set of $n$ points and just $n$ distinct points?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

What is the difference between saying "given set of $n$ points" and just "given $n$ distinct points"?

Comment: It depends on how precise the author of the first phrase is being when they use "set." Sometimes people say "set of $n$ points" when they mean "multiset of $n$ points," and then the difference is that the $n$ points aren't necessarily distinct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If two points are *distinct*, that means that they cannot be equivalent (however you want to define *equivalent*). So "*$n$ distinct points*" are $n$ points such that no pair of them are equivalent. Usually though, if the points are in a *set* it is implied that the points must be distinct.

Typically these two phrases are not distinct.